# Ubuntu server 14.04 running on power edge 1950 not connecting to internet

Tags: networking, server, ssh, apache2, samba

I recently setup a web server to run my owncloud. It was working all fine, until I had a power outage and the server turned off unexpectedly (I don't have a UPS just yet).
When I turned it on none of my services were running (openssh-client, apache2, samba and the server wasn't connecting to my router). I got the network back (it now has the et0) but it will not connect to the internet, apache2 wont run, neither will the ssh or samba.

I'm new to servers so i'm not sure how to fix this, any help would be amazing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Place the DNS servers in /etc/network/interfaces, not in /etc/resolv.conf

Add this line at the bottom of your static configurations
dns-nameservers 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220 #OpenDNS' servers as example

Then run these commands in the terminal to restart the interface. 
sudo su

ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0

Hope this works!

Comment: This may not solve the situation.